# Redirecting when encountering an Ecircle SOAP API Error

Tags: php, api, soap

I'm experimenting with Ecircle soap api, currently i'm using it to send message to new users who sign up on my site. I'm trying to do an error handling so that when the API fails, the function will send me an email with the error and the user id/email and then return to the main function and continue on it's merry way. That way I'll be aware of the problem and the user will be able to continue what they're doing without any interference. Here's an example of a function :

```
function lookupuserbyemail($userinput)  {
    $ns = "http://webservices.ecircleag.com/rpcns";
    $client = new soapclient('http://webservices.ecircle-ag.com/soap/ecm.wsdl');

    $logonparams = array('realm' => "http://email.mywebsite.com",
                        'user' => "admin@hotmail.com",
                        'passwd' => "12345");

    // check if logon was successful
    $result = $client->logon($logonparams);
    if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    sendMsgToMe();
    return;
    }
    $sessionid = $result->logonReturn;

    // logon ok, now call the function
    $params = array('email' => $userinput,
                    'session' => $sessionid);
    $result = $client->lookupUserByEmail($params);

    //check if the function was executed properly
    if (is_soap_fault($result)) {     
        $result = "error";
        return $result;
    }

    // print the result 
    $userinfo = htmlspecialchars($result->lookupUserByEmailReturn);

    // now logout
    $params = array('session' => $sessionid);
    $client->logout($params);
    if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
        $result = "error";
        return $result;
    }
    return $userinfo;
}
```

According to their wiki at http://developer.ecircle-ag.com/apiwiki/wiki/SynchronousSoapAPI#section-SynchronousSoapAPI-PHPSample, the code below is to detect an error or when an API function fails:

```
    $result = $client->logon($logonparams);
    if (is_soap_fault($result)) {
    sendMsgToMe();
    return;
    }
```

That is not the case however, instead of reporting the error, it just crashes and the user would see this :

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soapenv:Server.userException] com.ecircleag.webservices.EcMException: Error: blablablabla.
```

Evidently this is not so great since the user will be unable to continue if the ecircle service is down, therefore i would like to know if it's possible for the my code to continue running even when a SOAP error is logged.

Thank you :)